# Security - how to extract SOAPInput Auth Headers?

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I want to get SOAP Auth Headers from SOAPInput node (which are in Basic) for further processing. The problem is they aren't visible in trace/debug and somehow they are still used for authorization. From what I saw in docs IIB stores security tokens and uses them in some nodes when it's needed. The problem is my flow is a bit complex and I need to retrieve this base64 encoded string.

I tried to make security profile and apply to my flow inside BAR file but didn't noticed any change:

```
mqsicreateconfigurableservice broker -c SecurityProfiles -o viewAuth -n mapping,mappingConfig,passwordValue -v "WS-Trust v1.3 STS",http://linktomyservice:7800/service,PLAIN
```

Thank you.

Comment: SOAP header is part of the SOAP XML, you should be able to parse the XML and extract whatever  is required. Please correct me if there is some other kind of header you are looking at which is not part of SOAP XML.

Comment: @frabar if you send SOAP request from software such as SoapUI, your auth token will be stored inside HTTP Header, not a SOAP one.

Comment: Okay. I am assuming you are talking about adding HTTP basic auth header by clicking "Add New Authorization" in the soap ui tool

Comment: @frabar exactly! Thank you for your interest by the way. I believe it has something to do with setting right policy settings but I'm unsuccessful with these lately -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622285/iib-bip4761e-the-message-flow-attempted-to-use-securityprofiles-policy

Comment: filemono - could you please try and let me know if my below answer helped. I tried the same and it worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using SOAPUI, when you add basic authentication header by clicking "Add New Authorization" you have to enter username/password. Just below in the same window you have a field called "Pre-emptive auth". You have to select "Authenticate Pre-emptively" after which in IIB you see the authorization field getting populated under HTTPHeader. Below is an extract of http input header that I pulled by running IIB toolkit in debug mode.

```
HTTPInputHeader
X-Original-HTTP-Command:CHARACTER:POST http://XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding:CHARACTER:gzip,deflate
Content-Type:CHARACTER:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction:CHARACTER:""
Authorization:CHARACTER:Basic asdfsdfasdfasdfsdf
Content-Length:CHARACTER:254
```

To save the Authorization, you can use the below esql statement to save Authorization value in the Environment tree.

```
SET Environment.Authorization = InputRoot.HTTPInputHeader."Authorization";
```

I tried a small POC with IIB and it worked for me.

Comment: Turns out I was missing "Authenticate Pre-emptively" all this time. Thanks!